# why webappclassloader retains more heap space? how to resolve?

Tags: classloader, tomcat8, heap-dump, vs-web-application-project, catalina

[Heap Dump Screen SHot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiUok.png)

As you can see in the picture why the webappclassloader retained heap this high?

Does this indicate towards any problem?

If it is, then how to resolve it?